# Auto logout after log in

Tags: 16.04, vmware, login-screen

A few days ago I apt-get installed `vim-gtk`, when suddenly the installation stopped and I killed my VM (Without letting it finish the installation).
Ever since then, when I try to log in, after entering the password I see the screen loading but suddenly it logs out to the login screen again (after few seconds)...

1. I'm using Ubuntu desktop 16.04
2. Same behaviour when I log in with different users or guest
3. Still, can have root terminal when logging through **ubuntu recovery mode**

Any ideas how to fix it?
Thanks...

Comment: Why error are you getting when you boot into recovery mode?

Comment: No errors while booting into recovery mode, as I said I'm able to get root terminal using recovery mode.